# Disable hardware acceleration for Flash player in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash, youtube

The latest official version (and supposedly the last version for Linux) of Flash player has some interesting issues on Linux systems. The biggest issues which have summarily been confirmed on the Ubuntu forums are:

- YouTube videos have a red / blue color overlay
- Flash content shows through on other windows

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commonly accepted solution to this issue appears to be disabling hardware acceleration for Flash player. This is usually accomplished by right-clicking the Flash content, selecting `Settings` and then uncheck the `Enable Hardware Acceleration` option, but in the affected version of Flash player, it isn't possible to uncheck that particular option (clicking it does absolutely nothing). As such, the following two work-arounds exist for disabling hardware acceleration:

- **Method 1:** Create (or edit, if it already exists) the file `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` and add the following configuration parameter to it: `EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=0`
- **Method 2:** Open a YouTube video and enable fullscreen mode. Then right-click, select `Settings` and uncheck the `Enable Hardware Acceleration` option. For some reason this only seems to work when Flash player is in fullscreen mode.

Method 2 fixed it for me.

Comment: Method 1 fixed problems for me. I couldn't even get to the flash settings otherweise. Thanks for mentioning that config file.