# Can't disable hardware acceleration in Adobe Flash Player 11.2.202.251 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flash-player, hardware-acceleration

With the new release of Flash Player for Ubuntu I'm not even able to disable hardware acceleration to avoid that frustrating channel management that overlays a sort of blue pattern on each video.

I'd really like to get rid of it: I right-clicked on the running plugin, went to settings and then tried to remove the tick with no success.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/434762/disable-hardware-acceleration-for-flash-player-in-linux (also has a solution with a config file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to try as suggested in the Adobe forums [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891337):

1. Navigate to the [Find Flash Player Version page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html#main_Find_Flash_Player_version_type_and_capabilities__Flash_developers_only_).
2. Verify that you are in the section titled "Find Flash Player version type and capabilities (Flash developers only)".
3. Right click on the listed Player *version number* and select "Settings".
4. The Settings dialog will appear, change the tab at the bottom to display (if not already there) and uncheck (or if you'd like to enable, check) the "Enable hardware acceleration" check-box.
5. Close and restart your browser.